# automatically re-arrange the layout in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, silverlight

I have an aspx page, where initially i will define the layout (say table with 3x3) and corresponding div in each cell holding the content.

This is configured by administrator. So when the administrator is logged in, i will show all the configured items. But if the user logged in is not an administrator (say someother role), so this user may not have permission to view all the content(e.g content in cell 4 and 7 should not be shown).

In this case, how i make the page to occupy the empty space of cell 4 nad cell 7 by other cells contents? Is there any css styling/ asp controls which will automatically handle this kind of scenario's?

I can acheive this in Silverlight/WPF using a main StackPanel and defining each rows as child StackPanels and making the panel and control's vertical/horizontal alignment property to 'Stretch'. But how can i achieve this is in asp.net.?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [fluid css layout](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=fluid+css+layout). Short answer, use divs instead of a table. I'll leave the long answer for someone better than I at design.

Comment: I'm with jrummell, i'd rather use a ul, ol, or simply divs than a table to achieve what you want

Comment: Ya i am trying to use div. But it has 2 cases, 1. I need to set the width/height of div in % - if that is case, if one div is to be hidden, other divs will not occupy the space 2. I can set width/height of div as 'auto' - in this case, i cant able strech the div's space to occupy fully. How to address this?